# Sorting movie titles into CSV

Tags: sorting, powershell, csv

I've got a media server at home, and I've created a script that pulls all the file names and sorts them before putting them into a CSV. My only problem is that it sorts alphanumeric, but from a movie titles perspective, I'd like to ignore "A", "An", and "The". Is there a way to ignore those strings and have the sort work correctly without actually altering the file name in the CSV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can sort multiple objects into order by any property, and if none of the properties are quite what you want then you can provide a scriptblock to `Sort-Object` with some code "*do xyz to each object*" and it will sort them based on the output of the scriptblock - and that will only be used for sorting, it won't change anything.

So calculate the name without the leading words `A, An, The` using any code you want to. Here, I'm cooking with regex because it's quick, tasty and does case-insensitive matching by default:

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property { $_.Name -replace '^(A|An|The).' }
```

But you can do something just as effective with the plain ingredients around your kitchen:

```
Function Mangle-FilmName
{
    param($file)

    $name = $file.Name.ToLower()

    if ($name.startswith('an'))
    {
        $name.Substring(4)
    }
    elseif ($name.startswith('the')
    {
        $name.Substring(5)
    }
    ...
    else 
    {
        $name
    }
}

Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property Mangle-FilmName
```

Or with `switch` statements or loops over arrays of words, and/or/etc.

Comment: Somehow I never knew about the script block option.  Thanks for that.  Shouldn't the regex look like this - `'^(A |An |The )'` - though?  Or maybe even this - `'^(A *|An *|The *)'`

Comment: @JasonBoyd good catch, I was half thinking `'^(A|An|The) '` but forgot to put the space at the end. I've edited it in as a `.` so it will match whatever following character, stealing the idea from DAXaholic that it might be a name like `the_name_here.mpg` instead of a space.

Comment: This will only remove the names from the beginnend of the file names which the OP did not mention explicitly - DAX's answer takes care of that. But what's desired only the OP knows currently :)

Comment: @tengobash if they were at the end of the filename, they wouldn't be changing the sort order. And I didn't want to break film names like `Attack of the clones` with `the` in the middle, because sorting ignoring short words in the middle seems completely weird to me. But who knows, no examples means a vague answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! After testing it out it looks like the proper regex is `'^(A |An |The )'` as @JasonBoyd pointed out

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like the following.
Due to missing sample data I don't know the structure of your file names (word separators etc.) but you can customize the following code to your needs. What the code essentially does is splitting the base file name by separators `'_'`, `' '` and `'.'`, filters out your ignored words (`'The'`, `'A'`, `'An'` etc.) and joins back the parts to a single string.
Please note that at the end of this, the file names are compared without their initial word separators (i.e. `'The_Blue_House.mpg'` and `'The.Blue.House.mpg'` would be considered the same) which IMHO is a good thing but your needs may be different.

Hope that helps

---

```
$wordSeparator = '_| |\.'
$ignoredWords = @(
    'The'
    'A'
    'An'
    # add more
)

filter sortableFileName {
    ($_ -split $wordSeparator | ? { $_ -notin $ignoredWords }) -join ''
}

Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object { $_.BaseName | sortableFileName } # | Export-CSV
```

---

[image: Script in action]